# Outlook 2010 Delay Sending Rule

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, rules

I'm trying to figure out if I'm able to set up two rules for delaying the sending of messages from Outlook.

We have one set up for some of our users that delays the sending by 2 minutes, if the mail is being sent to a client. I would like to set up a second rule for internal delay of 1 minute, but having trouble.

Is it possible to have both active without conflict? Essentially, if the mail is being sent to a client, we definitely want a delay. If mostly internal, but 1 client, then delay. Finally, if only internal, just a smaller delay.

Our external delay is as follows and works perfectly fine: apply after send, with @ in recipient's address, defer by 2 mins, except with our organization name in address.

Any ideas without using VBA? Seems like I need more complex logic, but can't quite figure it out.

Comment: There's a good chance you'd probably need to use VBA due to complexity, why are you against it?

Answer (score 0):

Just create two rules (place them to the bottom of the list):

1. With client in recipient's address then delay, stop processing more rules.
2. With organization in recipient's address except client then smaller delay.